# How to get Guid from SqlDataReader uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-migration

SQL Server 2008 (version 10.50.2550).

I have a select query to return a single column of type uniqueidentifier.

I want to get this into a C# variable of type Guid.

All of the following methods result in exceptions.

reader is of type SqlDataReader.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

    if (reader.Read())
    {       
        Guid guid = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("integ_schemehistoryId")); //1

        Guid guid = Guid.Parse((string)reader["integ_schemehistoryId"]); //2

        Guid guid = (Guid)reader["integ_schemehistoryId"]; //3

        Guid guid = new Guid((string)reader["integ_schemehistoryId"]); //4

        Guid guid = Guid.Parse(reader["integ_schemehistoryId"].ToString()); //5
    }

}
```

Error for 1:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()
```

Error for 2:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()
```

Error for 3:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()
```

Error for 4:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()
```

Error for 5:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `GetGuid` should work. I would advise *against* any approach which performs two string conversions unnecessarily. Please give details of the error you get when calling `GetGuid`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which does that?

Comment: Anything using `Guid.Parse`. I'd expect your last attempt to be okay too. *Any* time you say "I get errors" or "it doesn't compile" in a Stack Overflow question, you should specify what those errors are. As it is, it looks like the first and last versions should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet see edit for error for the last version

Comment: @cja: You said they were *compile-time* errors. Those are exceptions, which occur as *execution-time*. *Please* be more careful about being precise in your information... you've wasted everyone's time chasing mythical compile-time failures.

Comment: Now added errors for all three methods, and corrected the second method @JonSkeet

Comment: I'm now very confused about how *both* errors 2 and 3 can occur. My guess is that they occur on different rows... I'm not surprised casting to `string` fails, but given that the cast fails *saying it's a GUID*, it's unclear why the cast to `Guid` would fail.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is true. My IDE is not Visual Studio and it is a little confusing.

Comment: @cja: Regardless of IDE, you should be able to tell the difference between "failing to compile" and an exception. Do either error 1 or error 3 have a nested exception at all? It looks like somehow you've got bad data, but it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't tell whether there are nested exceptions using my development environment. (It's Simego Data Synchronisation Studio.)

Comment: Does this work? `Guid guid = Guid.Parse(reader["integ_schemehistoryId"].ToString());`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling No. See latest edit.

Comment: @cja I think the stack trace for #5 is wrong; I don't see a call to Guid.Parse() in there anywhere. I would have expected a FormatException. Instead there's some sort of SqlException listed, which has nothing to do with Guid.Parse(). One last thought: if the stack trace is correct, are you sure that you're executing the code that you think you're executing?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling As written elsewhere on this page, I'm not using Visual Studio - it's a data migration tool that allows me to write C# to massage data. So I can't be totally sure, but as far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you agree with my assertion that the stack trace seems wrong for #5? Even if it's not under VS, it's c#, so we should be seeing a `FormatException` instead of a `SqlException`, no?

Comment: @cja It's almost like you re-ran the code for #3 again. The stack trace is identical. (Not accusing you of that; just pointing it out.)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: No - look at the stack trace carefully; the problem is in `Read`. I believe the code is reading the data with a known schema, and converting it to a GUID at *that* point. It's not getting as far as calling `Guid.Parse`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, excellent point... and one which you made, in your answer, now that I've re-read it. For grins (and assuming he has the capability), he could try changing the commandtext of the SqlCommand to include a CAST to VARCHAR(38) to see if it gets him past that line of code...

Comment: @cja Can you trying changing your `SqlCommand.CommandText` to wrap the uniqueidentifier column in a `CAST('uniqueidfield' AS varchar(38))` to see if you get past the `Reader.Read()`?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm way past this problem now, but thanks for the thought

Comment: @cja Sure thing... glad you have a solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is something wrong either with your data or your SQL. The first and third approaches should work - personally I'd use the first form, as it's the clearest in my view.

But look at the stack trace:

...
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()

Note that it's the `Read()` call which is failing, *not* `GetGuid` or the indexer.

My guess is that your property is being fetched several times, and *sometimes* it works - which is why you were getting a cast exception in your second approach - but for *some* rows, it fails due to some problem with the data or the SQL. As we've no idea where your data is coming from, we can't help you beyond that diagnosis, but that's where you should look next.

Comment: Left join fetching duplicate keys?  That'll do it.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers suggest, you should try:

```
Guid guid = Guid.Parse(reader["integ_schemehistoryId"].ToString())
```

You might also want to check your stored procedures and your table, there may be something wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

That error is being generated from SQL. In other words there something wrong with you SQL command text. Not your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Guid guid = new Guid((string)reader["integ_schemehistoryId"]);
```

Comment: Yes, see the question. (Maybe you posted this before I edited the question.)

Comment: I don't think you have. `new Guid(...` uses the constructor, your question states that you've tried the static method `Guid.Parse`, the `SQLDataReader` method `.GetGuid` and directly casting to `(Guid)` from the object in `Reader`, none of the 3 cases use `new`, which is the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I get: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
   at Simego.DataSync.DynamicColumns.DataSourceRowOverride.get_EpochSchemeHistoryID()

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `Guid.Parse` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx)

```
Guid guid = return Guid.Parse((string)reader["integ_schemehistoryId"]);
```

Comment: See my second attempt in the question.

Comment: @cja: Well you're passing in the wrong data type - it's possible that this would work if called *correctly*, though it's not the best way of doing it.

Comment: @cja convert reader value to string since Parse method expect string as param

Comment: I downvoted when the answer was just "Try by using Guid.Parse method"

Comment: @cja I also provide u a link how to use Guid.Parse method properly

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I did when I added my last comment

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle database:

```
"ID" RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

This code worked for me:

```
using (IDataReader dr = ... )
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var Id = new Guid();
            if (!(dr["ID"] is DBNull)){
                Id = new Guid((byte[])dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("ID")));
            }                   
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case with .Net and MSSQL Server this code helped me to get the data and to avoid exceptions:

```
Guid guid = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("integ_schemehistoryId")) ?
     (Guid?)null : reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("integ_schemehistoryId"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    object val = reader[0];
    Guid g;
    if ( Guid.TryParse(val, out g) )
    {
        return g;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + g == null ? string.Empty : g.ToString());   
    }
```